# Spfile and Pfile not created during installtion of Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need your help concerning an issue with oracle 11g installation, i installed it while connected to a domain account (and still connected to it), after installation complete and a reboot i tried to startup Oracle using windows command line:

```
>sqlplus /nolog
>connect sys /as sysdba
>startup
```

After the startup command i get the following error:

`ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters`
`ORA-01565: error in identifying file  ORA-27041: unable to open file
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\dbs/spfileXE.ora`

When i manually went to spfile and file locations, i didn't find anyone of them.

now i am looking for a method to generate of create these files without having to reinstall Oracle 11g. Any ideas please?
PS : i have windows 10.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, while looking for pfile i was looking for something like  PFile.ora, have just found that it is named init.ora, sounds stupid but yeah :D